# Bootstrap columns in a php while loop

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I've read a ton of different ideas out there for this but can't seem to get any of them to work for my piece of code. Currently my products are displaying in a singular column but I'd like them to display in either a 3 or 4 column grid. Here's the code I have so far, hopefully someone can see where I'm going wrong.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <div class="container"> 
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <?php echo $row["ID"] . " - " . $row["item"] . "<br>";?>
            <img src="img/<?php echo $row["image"] ?>" style="width:150px;height:150px;"><br>
            <?php echo $row["description"] . " - $" . $row["price"]; ?>
        <form method="post" action="viewcart.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="item" value="<?php echo $row["item"]?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $row["price"]?>" />
            <button type="submit">Add To Cart</button>
       </form> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but the container outside the while loop

Comment: yes, why do you have the container inside the loop?

Comment: <div class="container"> must be outside of while loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `.container` being looped inside the `while` loop as well, which is the problem. The correct format is:

```
.container
  .row
    .col-XX-X
```

Put the `container` and the `row` outside and you are good to go.

```
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  echo '<div class="container"><div class="row">'; // You left a row. Change here.
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <?php echo $row["ID"] . " - " . $row["item"] . "<br>";?>
          <img src="img/<?php echo $row["image"] ?>" style="width:150px;height:150px;"><br>
          <?php echo $row["description"] . " - $" . $row["price"]; ?>
          <form method="post" action="viewcart.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="item" value="<?php echo $row["item"]?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $row["price"]?>" />
            <button type="submit">Add To Cart</button>
        </form> 
      </div>
<?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Praveen Kumar! This worked great. I haven't used bootstrap or CSS since I've moved on past just basic HTML so this concept escaped me.

Answer (score 0):

Put your container outside of while loop:

```
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
       echo '<div class="container">';
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <?php echo $row["ID"] . " - " . $row["item"] . "<br>";?>
                <img src="img/<?php echo $row["image"] ?>" style="width:150px;height:150px;"><br>
                <?php echo $row["description"] . " - $" . $row["price"]; ?>
            <form method="post" action="viewcart.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="item" value="<?php echo $row["item"]?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $row["price"]?>" />
                <button type="submit">Add To Cart</button>
           </form> 
         </div>
    <?php } // end while loop 
    ?>
       </div>
    <?php } //end if statement 
   ?>
```

Comment: That's a wrong code. Please check the PHP tags. Also explain something too.

Answer (score -4):

If you want more columns, make it like below:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The total number of columns when you add up, must be 12